# how to verify mysql backup file

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

**Is There any tool to verify the backup taken using mysqldump without manual restoration ?**

I have to take full backup daily so it is difficult for me to verify the backups daily by restoring them. As it will take time and also temporary disk space.

Please suggest me how to verify my backup online

Answer (score 4):

Start a dedicated Mysql server with as default engine blackhole (and maybe the only one) and engine_substitution enabled.
Then you can restore your mysqldump and monitor warning(s) and error(s) generated.

Maximum execution speed and no disk space taken ...

Hope this will help you