# MySQL verify backups

Tags: mysql, dump

There's standalone MySQL server 5.5 with no slaves. Daily dump is created using `mydumper` tool.

Is there any way to verify created dump (all tables are created, integrity, etc.) without restoring dump somewhere, using slaves, etc..?

Comment: Also what seems like a good idea here: [how to verify mysql backup file](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44399/how-to-verify-mysql-backup-file)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44893/34007) is one of the best posts I've seen on this (regular enough here) topic. Seems to be the quickest way to test a backup.

What you've got to remember is that **no** process is 100% cast-iron guaranteed to restore your databases - there's the thorny issue of money.

Basically, every extra 9 (3, 4, 5 nines) that you put on to your procedures will (my own rule of thumb here) put the price of your backup and restore procedures up by a 0 - i.e. a factor of 10! Are you going to be checking every backup you make? You can follow industry best practice and make it **crystal** clear that that is what you are doing (to your bosses/shareholders/stakeholders) and that if they want more guarantees, they'll have to pay and pay lots!

You can talk about clusters, master-slave replication, master-master, geo-replication, RAID10 SSD's - the number of solutions for HA MySQL is huge, but the prices get huge pretty fast also!

Best practice is testing backups ~ 6 weeks - a role for a junior DBA - you should take a full backup once a week with incremental backups every night when traffic is low (for MySQL I strongly recommend Percona's Open Source [XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup)).

Motto of the story, formulate a backup and restore plan **with** the other stakeholders (explaining the pros and cons - risk, cost &c.) and follow industry best practice and you won't go far wrong!